# Function does not return the value

Tags: javascript

```
function Increment()
{
  var counter = 100;
   function inner() 
    {
         counter += counter;
         return counter;
    }
}
var x = Increment();
console.log(x);
console.log(x);
console.log(x);
```

This is instruction of this code
Use JavaScript Closure/self invoking method to do the following:
a)Name the outer function as ‘Increment”.
b)Store 100 as a counterin the outer function.
c)Increment the counter by 100 in the inner functionand return.
d)Call “Increment” three times and store the returned value in a variable each time.
e)Log the final value in the web console (400 is the final valuefor the third call)
, but function does not return even the first value.

Can you guys see where the problem is?

Comment: minor piece of feedback — avoid using `var`, and use `let` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: Are those the actual instructions, word for word? To get the result they want, you'd need to return the `inner` function, call `Increment` only once, storing its result (the inner function) in a variable, then call that returned function multiple times.

Comment: ...at least if closures are the objective, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the "inner" function for it to execute.

And your Increment function Should return or update counter variable for it to take effect.

You should also declare the counter variable outside so you can increment it every time you call the "Increment" Function.

If you declare it inside it will just reset every time you call the "Increment" function.

you can do it like this.

```
function Increment()
{
    function inner() 
    {
        counter += 100;
        return counter;
    }
    return inner();
}

var counter = 100;

console.log(Increment());
console.log(Increment());
console.log(Increment());
```

Comment: I ran your code on firefox, but it still says undefined..

Comment: Your code still isn't `return`ing, which is why it is still logging `undefined`...

Comment: return counter = inner(counter);

return the counter from increment function

Comment: I have updated the code, for you to continue the counter value

Comment: I it short and readably, but do you really need to create inner function, you can. do increment without it.

Comment: I have updated it so you will have the target final value of 400

Answer (score 0):

You will not only have to call the inner function but also return its result. The below code works

```js
var counter = 100; 
function Increment()
    {
       function inner() 
        {
             counter += counter;
             return counter;
        }
    return inner();
    }
    var x = Increment();
    var y = Increment();
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works but it should increment every time I call the function. How should I save the value?

Comment: function Increment()
        {
          var counter = 100;
           function inner() 
            {
                 counter += counter;
                 return counter;
            }
        return inner();
        }
        var x = Increment();
        console.log(x);
    x = Increment();
        console.log(x);
    x = Increment();
        console.log(x);    //This is how I changed it but it still gives me only 200.

Comment: The variable counter should be initialized outside the function. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the inner function three times, so you need to return the inner function in the outer function and call it.

```js
function Increment()
{
  var counter = 100;
   function inner() 
    {
         counter += counter;
         return counter;
    }
    return inner;
}
var x = Increment();
console.log(x());
console.log(x());
console.log(x());
```

If the final value needs to be 400, you can rewrite your function a little bit like this:

```js
function Increment() {
  var counter = 0;

  function inner() {
    counter += counter || 100;
    return counter;
  }
  return inner;
}
var x = Increment();
console.log(x());
console.log(x());
console.log(x());
```

Comment: function Increment()
        {
          var counter = 100;
           function inner() 
            {
                 counter += counter;
                 return counter;
            }
        return inner();
        }
        var x = Increment();
        console.log(x);
    x = Increment();
        console.log(x);
    x = Increment();
        console.log(x); // I changed my code to this but it still gives me only 200, do you guys have some idea, it should keep increment.

Answer (score 0):

`Increment()` returns nothing, or `undefined`.

If you expect Increment to return the value of counter, simply add a `return` statement.

```
 function Increment() {
     let counter = 100;
     function inner() {
         counter += counter;
         return counter;
     }
     return counter;
}
let x = Increment();
console.log(x); // 100
console.log(x); // no change, since `Increment()` 
console.log(x); // was only called once
```

Keep in mind, `inner` is never called — if you wanted inner to do something, call `inner()`. Additionally, keep in mind that `counter` is declared within `Increment()`, meaning that each time you call it, it is redeclared (and reset to 100)

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions won't produce the result they anticipate.

Here's probably what they actually want.

```js
function Increment() {
  var counter = 100;

  function inner() {
    counter += 100;
    return counter;
  }
  
  return inner;
}
var innerFunc = Increment();

var a = innerFunc();
var b = innerFunc();
var c = innerFunc();

console.log(c);
```

Two things changed in `Increment`.

First, the `inner` function increments the counter by `100`. This is needed because `counter` is mutated, so `counter += counter` causes `counter` to increase by the most recently updated version.

Second, the `inner` function becomes the return value of `Increment`.

So you'd only call `Increment` once, and store its result in a variable. That variable holds the `inner` function you returned. Now every time you call that function, it increments the `counter` variable by `100`, and returns its new value.

This is a proper demonstration of closures.